# Was there a HttpResponse.HeadersWritten equivalent before .Net 4.5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-4.0

I'm doing some maintenance on an old legacy web site. We have an issue where a aspx page writes a large CSV file to the response and then calls Response.End. After this we have a HttpModule that tries to write to the response Headers. The trouble is that if the CSV is large enough the response buffer fills up and gets written to the client before the HttpModule runs. When the HttpModule then writes its header it fails.

In .Net 4.5 there is a property on the HttpResponse called [HeadersWritten](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.headerswritten(v=vs.110).aspx) and my plan was to check this in the HttpModule and not attempt to set the header. This is acceptable in the case of this file download. However this property was only introduced in .Net 4.5 and we are still using .Net 4. The team are reluctant to upgrade right now,

My question is was there an equivalent to the HeadersWritten property before .Net 4.5 introduced it?

Comment: If there was an equivalent, why would they have introduced `HeadersWritten`?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I'm not looking for a single method call. Rather a snippet of code. It is possible to imagine they added it to make what would have been fifteen awkward lines of code a simple single line.

Comment: @MartinBrown you can check the MS.NET code if you like here - https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/HttpResponse.cs,fa6ed5622db1799a